# In DevExpress Controls, the Property VisibleIndex of BandedGridColumn does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I write the following code to hide the particular column:

```
(_view as BandedGridView).Columns[j].VisibleIndex = -1;
```

And this worked

However, I want to change the order of the column by following code:

```
(_view as BandedGridView).Columns[j].VisibleIndex = i;
```

But this does not worked

Ask for help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.BandedGrid.BandedGridColumn.VisibleIndex.property), assigning value to `VisibleIndex` property greater than -1 attempting to move the column has no effect:

> Setting the VisibleIndex property to -1 hides the column. In this
>   case, the column header is displayed within the Customization Form
>   (provided that the column's OptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm
>   option is enabled).
>
> **Note that assigning values greater than -1 has no effect.** To change
>   the column's position among visible columns in Banded Grid Views, use
>   the **GridBandColumnCollection.MoveTo** method.

Assume that you have a GridBand in designer:

```
private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.BandedGrid.GridBand GridBand1;
```

You can use [`MoveTo`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.BandedGrid.GridBandColumnCollection.MoveTo.method) method to change column position instead:

```
GridBand1.Columns.MoveTo(i, [BandedGridColumn]);
```

NB: The `[BandedGridColumn]` refers to `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.BandedGrid.BandedGridColumn` object names declared in the designer.

Similar issue:

[Strange Behavior when setting VisibleIndex in BandedGridView after user customization](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B204046/strange-behavior-when-setting-visibleindex-in-bandedgridview-after-user-customization)

Answer (score 0):

```
GridCell CurrentCell { get; set ; }
private void gridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         CurrentCell = null;
        GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridView1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
        if (hitInfo.HitTest == GridHitTest.RowCell)
        {
            CurrentCell = new GridCell(hitInfo.RowHandle, hitInfo.Column);
        }
    }
}
```

Result: gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = CurrentCell.RowHandle;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).